# Can't discover peripheral using service UUID

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to detect a cycling power meter I have. I used the app LightBlue to determine the power meter's service UUID, which is E9410100-B434-446B-B5CC-36592FC4C724.

But when I use CBCentralManager to discover devices with this UUID, nothing is discovered:

```
manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID(string: "E9410100-B434-446B-B5CC-36592FC4C724")], options: nil)
```

Is there a shortened version of this UUID I should be using?

Comment: Could you also show your LightBlue screenshot and the `CBCentralManagerDelegate` you implemented? Can it scan other devices? Can it scan your cycling power meter if you use `withServices: nil` ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't search for a specific device's identifier (This is unique per iOS device anyway).  Rather, you search for peripherals that are advertising the service in which you are interested.

In the case of [cycling power](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.cycling_power.xml), this is 0x1818

You want:

```
manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID(string: "1818")], options: nil)
```

Comment: Then you need to show more code; Are you sure your delegate is created correctly?  Is your `manager` not `nil`.  What happens if you specify `nil` for the services array?